# Keep status bar app from showing icon in the dock

Tags: macos, cocoa

I created a status bar app for the mac a few weeks ago. However, whenever I run the app, the dock icon shows up alone with the item in the status bar. Is there a way to keep the app from appearing in the dock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't write comments but to what @Michael Dautermann wrote I'd suggest using the `LSUIElement` key.

You've said that it's a status bar app, so it has a UI.

> LSUIElement (String - OS X) specifies whether the app runs as an agent app. If this key is set to “1”, Launch Services runs the app as an agent app. Agent apps do not appear in the Dock or in the Force Quit window. Although they typically run as background apps, they can come to the foreground to present a user interface if desired. A click on a window belonging to an agent app brings that app forward to handle events.
>   The Dock and loginwindow are two apps that run as agent apps.

Despite what the docs say it is a String so you can also set this as bool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [set the LSBackgroundOnly key](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-109268) in your app's "Info.plist" file.

Comment: NSApplication also provides hooks to this if you want to optionally allow it.